# awk command to take a variable

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a txt file with 3 rows, now I want to multiply a variable value with the 2nd column. Given below is my requirement.

```
cat sample.txt
    ABC,123,qwe123
    ASD,456,asd123
    VBN,6532,wqe123
```

I have a variable, colum=100. I want to multiply this variable with 2nd column using awk. The code I tried is:

```
cat sample.txt | awk -F , '{print $1","$2*$($colum)","$3}'

My expected output is:
        ABC,12300,qwe123
        ASD,45600,asd123
        VBN,653200,wqe123
```

Please note that I want to perform this awk using the variable only, I dont want to directly multiply column 2 with 100.

Comment: Use the builtin `ENVIRON` array to access environment variables: `colum=100 awk -F , '{print $1","$2*ENVIRON["colum"]","$3}' sample.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a variable to awk using -v option

```
cat sample.txt | awk -v colum="100" -F, '{print $1 "," $2 * colum, $3}'
```

Comment: The updated command seems to work for me.

Comment: What if the variable value is not a direct value, the colum value is obtained from some other calculation. How do I pass it to the awk command?

Comment: You can just assign column=$VAR, where VAR is a shell variable.

Comment: Got it, my problem solved :) thanks